# Why does my UITabBar move off the screen when I have an incoming call?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uiview, uitabbarcontroller

95% of my app's views work fine with an incoming call/maps-open/expanded-status-bar.

The only thing that is a bit off, is my main UITabBar.

If I switch tabs on the UITabBar, it will push the UITabBar off screen.

However, let's say I'm on the first tab. If I push a view on to the navigation stack, and then back out... the UITabBar will be fine. It will be perfectly where it should be. Until I change tabs again, at which point it will animate down, and about 40% of it will be hidden off screen.